# Ошибка Fatal error: Class 'Db' not found

Tags: php, классы, pdo, include

Есть файл lorem.php, в нём есть код:

```
    <?php

    class Header
    {
        public static function getData() {


            $db = Db::getConnection();
```

В этом файле всё работает отлично, запросы к базе выполняются.
А вот когда я хочу получить переменную из этого файла в другом:

```
<?php


        include_once('/../models/lorem.php');

        $resultid = Header::getData();
```

То мне выдаёт ошибку : **Fatal error: Class 'Db' not found in D:\wamp\www\models\lorem.php**

Наверное полезной информацией будет то, что второй файл вызывается Ajax-запросом в html файле, в другой директории. Уже перепробовал всё в разных варриациях, ничего не помогает ...

Answer (score 1):

Просто напросто он у вас не находит файл с классом Db.

У вас в lorem.php прописан импорт класса Db, и указан относительный путь к нему.
Когда вы вызываете include, все относительные пути включенного файла начинают считаться относительно расположения файла В КОТОРЫЙ он включается.

Поэтому, если у вас в lorem.php написано

```
require 'class/Db.php';
```

То при выполнении

```
include_once('/../models/lorem.php');
```

`Db.php` ищется не в `/../models/class`, а в `class/` относительно каталога запуска основного скрипта.

Почитайте про [автоматическую загрузку классов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Дело в том, файл с подключением к базе вызывается в фронт контроллере index.php, с помощью
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Db.php');
Путь должен быть указан для всех одинаково, на сколько я понимаю, от корня директории к файлу Db.php

Comment: @BimBam Вы опишите полностью, как именно у вас происходят цепочки вызовов в обоих случаях. Это 100% косяк с путями до файла класса, и dirname далеко не всегда панацея.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда указывайте абсолютные пути к файлам через константу **__DIR__**

```
require __DIR__ . /classes/db.php
include_once(__DIR__ . '/../models/lorem.php');
```